# How to deploy a war file in production?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, tomcat

I have a war file of a web application which I want to deploy in production mode. I am confused as to how I should go about it. I was currently working Apache Tomcat to develop and debug the application. Will tomcat be suitable for a production release as well if I'm expecting heavy traffic on the web application? If not please suggest how should I go about it.

Comment: Reason for down-voting the question?

Comment: Questions on how to solve technical problem X with software tool Y are much better suited for Stackoverflow than for SE.SE. If you can reword your question in a more tool agnostic manner like "how to deploy a war file to an application server" it might fit here. However, make sure you did some research first, I found http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html in 30 seconds using Google - so when you ask on this site or on SO, you should explain why this link to the Tomcat docs does not help you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but my question is about if tomcat is the right choice or not because I have this notion that Tomcat is only for "Development" stage. I wanted to know what would be the correct way to deploy a war file if it is intended to be used in production. I already know how to deploy a war file using tomcat.

Comment: If your question is specificially about Tomcat, you should ask on SO, not here on SE.SE. And your clarification should not be buried in a comment, it should be part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a heavy traffic then you may use a load balancer. You may still use Tomcat but instead of using one Tomcat instance deploy to several servers with each having one running Tomcat. Connect these Tomcats with a load balancer. The load balancer will route the client requests to the different Tomcats, so it ...

- Distributes client requests or network load efficiently across
  multiple servers
- Ensures high availability and reliability by sending
  requests only to servers that are online
- Provides the flexibility to
  add or subtract servers as demand dictates

You may search for it. Also i found this for you: https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/